# MSSQL Query Taking Expotentially Longer in PHP/PDO

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008, pdo

I'm writing a small tool for my boss that requires me to extract records from a FedEx flat file and then grab order data from our ERP.  I'm running into a serious bottleneck that is causing my queries to take longer than five seconds when run through PHP, and I'm turning to the collective for help.

App OS: LAMP Server w/ PHP 5.3.2
DB: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Once I grab an invoice, it gives me all our order numbers associated with the invoice.  These are almost always non-sequential, and the bigger invoices can have up to 3,000 order numbers.

Example:

`SELECT o.ORDER_NO, o.TRANSACTION_ID, o.SHIP_DATE, o.SHIP_CHRG, s.TRANSACTION_ID, s.ACTUAL_WGHT, s.PACKER, s.SHIP_DEPARTMENT, s.TRACKER_ID FROM o INNER JOIN s ON o.TRANSACTION_ID = s.TRANSACTION_ID AND o.ORDER_NO IN (86965,93616,93357,89475,90252,90249,93674,94029,88340,93044,89267,87340...)`

The above example has 2,744 ORDER_NOs it needs to grab. If I jump on my Windows client and use management studio, it returns results in just over half a second (274995 bytes).  If I do it in PHP, its taking 5.5 to 6 seconds.

I normally use PDO dblib to access my alien databases and I've tried direct query and prepared executes with no change. I even tried the code using built in mssql functions in PHP to no effect.

Is there anything I am missing that would allow me to get this time down?  My execution plans look good on the database server, so I'm leaning strongly to it being an issue with PHP.

Thanks in advance for any help you all may be able to provide!

Comment: PDO's overhead is fairly minimal. have you looked at how much of that 5-6 seconds is actually spent waiting for MySQL and how much is PHP overhead?

Comment: That's definitely a possibility.  I used debugDumpParams and am microtiming my query, but I'm at a loss to determine how else I can monitor this.

Comment: My other thought was that PHP somehow sends the query differently when its in an IN list.

Comment: PHP knows nothing of SQL. PDO knows very little about SQL as well, just enough to figure out where placeholders are in parametrized queries. All the actual sql processing is done in mysql.

Comment: mssql.  I totally hear you, but this kept me up last night so I was considering all rational and irrational possibilities :)

Comment: Heh. doh... my/ms... one lousy little letter... If nothing else, you should be able to enable query auditing/logging somewhere inside the admin console to see how long the actual query took.

Comment: Well, first off I just realized that I wrote a terrible query.  I'm doing an INNER JOIN on multiple conditionals one of which is this lousy list.  Swapping the AND for a WHERE shaved the query in half.

A buddy recommended that perhaps an IN statement was being treated poorly by the dblib driver and to swap it out for a very, very long OR qualification.

While it feels horrible to my senses, the query results return in under a second!

So I guess that solves this issue...for now?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7216/discussion-between-marc-b-and-vsack)

Comment: One optimization for a long in/or is to create a temporary table that you can join on, instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first off I just realized that I wrote a terrible query.

I'm doing an INNER JOIN on multiple conditionals one of which is this lousy list. Swapping the AND for a WHERE shaved the query in half.

A buddy recommended that perhaps an IN statement was being treated poorly by the dblib driver and to swap it out for a very, very long OR qualification. While it feels horrible to my senses, the query results return in under a second!

So I guess that solves this issue...for now?

Answer (score 1):

i have never worked with pdo but thought you can try this.  if this is the only process running, before you run the search query, upload the order list to a table.  then join to that table in the search.

```
insert into **order_list**
select 86965
union select 93616
union select 93357
union select 89475
```

or

```
insert into **order_list**
select 86965

insert into **order_list**
select 93616

insert into **order_list**
select 93357
```

then

```
SELECT o.ORDER_NO, o.TRANSACTION_ID, o.SHIP_DATE, o.SHIP_CHRG, s.TRANSACTION_ID,       s.ACTUAL_WGHT, s.PACKER, s.SHIP_DEPARTMENT, s.TRACKER_ID 
FROM o INNER JOIN s ON o.TRANSACTION_ID = s.TRANSACTION_ID 
INNER JOIN order_list oo ON o.ORDER_NO = oo.ORDER_NO
```